# why TCP state remain establish for a while after disable network card

Tags: tcp, window, winsock

I am testing a networking application, I notice that after I disable the network card, when I netstat -an, I can still see the TCP state still be Establish for a while. I would like to know that why the TCP State doesn't close immediately after the network card disable?

Answer (score 1):

Why should it?  The link might be enabled again, or there may be another route to the peer, or another route might become available.  In those cases, communication may continue without any failure at L3 and upwards.